# How would I parse specific JSON parameters using Regular Expressions in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, parsing

To make this question short and simple, I have the value "session" in my browsers local storage with this value:

```
{"id":992085,"token":"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiI5OTIwODUiLCJuYW1lIjoiYmNfZXg3bHRlZCBiY19leDdsdGVkYSIsImlhdCI6MTY2OTA0MT3fas48gj9joxNjc2ODE3OTc3LCJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL3dvcmtzcGFjZS5maXZlcnIuY29tIiwiYW5kY29Vc2VySWQiOjk5MjA4NSwiYW5kY29Sb2xlIjoiRnJlZWxhbmNlclJvbGUifQ.QvEyJ9Gq3jWG0zVROFyKf8-EKIufMyi6Ljwc1ioh9DQ","lastLoginDate":"2022-11-21T14:43:00.000Z","role":0,"email":"user_email@example.com"}
```

I'm writing a very simple bit of javascript in which I would like to parse the `992085` value and the `eyJ0eXAi.....` value and combine them into `992085:eyJ0eXAi.....` then base64 encode that value and make that it's own variable. The not-so-simple part is the regular expression needed to parse the values I'd like.
I know basic regEx but I've never even tried regEx in javascript.

What would be the proper javascript regular expression for my scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would not do this with a regular expression in Javascript. Use the built in JSON parser

```
obj = JSON.parse(s);
result = obj.id + obj.token;
```